# Taper Mesh Deform with Geometry Nodes

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

Hi there first post here. I am trying to achieve the effect of the *Simple Deform* Modifier set to *Taper* within *Geometry Nodes*. Using Blender 3.1.0

[image]

The picture to the left is my Geometry Nodes object - just a simple scattering of cylinders on a plane. To the right is the same object with a Simple Deform Modifier after the GeoNodes mod set to taper along the Z axis.

I would prefer to be able to do the same thing within the Geometry Node tree without using the deform modifier.

The main reason being that for the modifier to work I have to realize the instances, which I'd rather not do so I can use the instance objects' local texture coordinates for shading.

Surprisingliy I did not find many resources online on how to deform a mesh in GeoNodes. Any help and pointers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should multiply X and Y position by Z position:

[image]

Instances should be realized before scaling.

[image]

Comment: @Gorgious Of course.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. That's good to know. 

Sadly this solution still needs the *Realize Instances* node, which I was hoping to avoid. But it seems that I just have to realize the instances in order to be able to deform them (which kind of makes sense), so I guess I'll have to work around the coordinate issue in the shader.

Still, nice to have this solution which I find more elegant than the modifier stack. And it also helped me to better understand the concept behind instances and meshes in GeoNodes. So thank you again.